# Sending mails from ELMAH not throw the mailSettings in the web.config

Tags: asp.net, elmah

I'm using ELMAH (1.2.13605.2128) for error control on my asp.net websites.
This is working fine with the standard mail settings in the `web.config`:

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
    <network host="smtp.gmail.com" defaultCredentials="false"
    port="587" userName ="yourMailId@gmail.com" password="yourMailPassword" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

But so everyone can read the username and password for the mail account who has access to the `web.config`.

Is there a way to use the mail module without the `web.config`? Maybe using encrypted data from a database für the mail settings?

Comment: web.config supports encryption out of the box using the aspnet_regiis tool. Check out this for details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/zhhddkxy(v=vs.100)